# Can any trigonometric polynomial be written in euler's form?

Tags: fourier-analysis, trigonometric-series

A trigonometric polynomial can be written as:
$$\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k \cos(kx) + b_k \sin(kx))$$

My math books says, that ANY trigonometric polynomial can be written in euler's form:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k e^{ikx} = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k \cos(kx) + i b_k  \sin(kx))$$

Using this form, however, the coefficients must be complex.

My question is now, given the fact that $a_k $ must be complex and sin is imaginary using the euler's form, is it really possible to rewrite ANY (real-valued) trigonometric polynomial from the cos-sin form in the euler form for simplicity? If yes, how is it possible? In the second definition the coefficients are complex and sin is imaginary.

Comment: This can be avoided if one works with a symmetric series: $$\sum_{k=-N}^N a_k e^{ikx}.$$ In this case one may use real coefficients (sans the $i$ that sticks around for sine).

Comment: @CameronWilliams could you please elaborate a bit more? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure, if you use the identity $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{ix} + e^{-ix})$ and $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{ix})$, you can turn your initial expression into something of the form that I have in my first comment.

Comment: @CameronWilliams ok thanks a lot Cameron. So just as a confirmation, if the Sum goes from -N to N, everything clears out and then the statement that any trigonometric polynomial can be written in euler's form is true? And using euler's form with the sum from 1 to N, then this statement holds false?

Comment: @smalllearner: index of summation is irrelevant, if you look at the expression for sine via complex exponent, you'll see that $i$ will cancel out and you'll have real coefficients. In fact, complex form provided by Cameron is the most commonly used as it's easier to work with.